# Https proxy decode encoded data node js

Tags: node.js, express, https, proxy

I am trying to setup a proxy for http and https. Here is my code,

```
const http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var net = require('net');
const config = require('./config');
 
let proxify = function (req, res) {
  var urlObj = url.parse(req.url);
  var target = urlObj.protocol + '//' + urlObj.host;
 
  if (!req.headers['x-target']) req.headers['x-target'] = target;
  req.headers['x-proxy-username'] = config.username;
  req.headers['x-proxy-password'] = config.password;
 
  console.log(target);
 
  console.log('Proxy HTTP request for:', target);
 
  var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
  proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
    console.log('proxy error', err);
    res.end();
  });
 
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: config.server, changeOrigin: true });
};
 
var httpserver = http.createServer(proxify).listen(2890); //this is the port your clients will connect to
 
const httpsserver = https
  .createServer(
    {
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl_cert/cert.pem'),
      key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl_cert/key.pem'),
    },
    proxify
  )
  .listen(2891);
 
var regex_hostport = /^([^:]+)(:([0-9]+))?$/;
 
var getHostPortFromString = function (hostString, defaultPort) {
  var host = hostString;
  var port = defaultPort;
 
  var result = regex_hostport.exec(hostString);
  if (result != null) {
    host = result[1];
    if (result[2] != null) {
      port = result[3];
    }
  }
 
  return [host, port];
};
 
httpserver.addListener('connect', function (req, socket, bodyhead) {
  var hostPort = getHostPortFromString(req.url, 443);
  var hostDomain = hostPort[0];
  var port = parseInt(hostPort[1]);
  console.log('Proxying HTTPS request for:', hostDomain, port);
 
  req.headers['x-target'] = 'http://' + hostDomain + ':' + port;
  req.headers['x-proxy-username'] = config.username;
  req.headers['x-proxy-password'] = config.password;
 
  var proxyHost = new URL(config.server);
 
  var proxySocket = new net.Socket();
 
  proxySocket.connect(
    { port: proxyHost.port, host: proxyHost.hostname },
    function () {
      console.log('bodyhead', bodyhead.toString()); //debug
      proxySocket.write(bodyhead);
      socket.write(
        'HTTP/' + req.httpVersion + ' 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n'
      );
    }
  );
 
  proxySocket.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('proxy data chunk', chunk.toString()); // debug
    socket.write(chunk);
  });
 
  proxySocket.on('end', function () {
    socket.end();
  });
 
  proxySocket.on('error', function () {
    socket.write('HTTP/' + req.httpVersion + ' 500 Connection error\r\n\r\n');
    socket.end();
  });
 
  socket.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('data chunk', chunk.toString('utf8')); // debug
    proxySocket.write(chunk);
  });
 
  socket.on('end', function () {
    proxySocket.end();
  });
 
  socket.on('error', function () {
    proxySocket.end();
  });
});
```

Don't judge me too hard, just trying to get it working first.

When proxying http with windows 10 proxy settings, it works fine. But when I am trying to proxy https, it logs encoded data like `↕►♦♦♦☺♣♣♣♠♠☺↕3+)/1.1♣♣☺

☺↔ \s☻�t�DQ��g}T�c\‼sO��♦��U��ޝ∟-☻☺☺+♂
→→♥♦♥♥♥☻♥☺♥☻☻j☺§�` and gives a 400 bad request.I don't know if its the encoding of https response or something else, I have no idea what i am doing at this point and need help.

Answer (score -1):

it is because https uses tls/ssl to encrypt the data.